# Set label text in QTabWidget tab

Tags: qt, qt-designer, qtabwidget

I have `QTabWidget` on my form and two tabs on it. These tabs have standard text *Tab1* and *Tab2*.
How can I change it?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about Qt Designer, since it defaults to showing two tabs (called "Tab 1" and "Tab 2") when you add a `QTabWidget` through the interface.

If so, click on the tab you want to rename, then in the *Property Editor* (if you can't find it make sure it's visible by using the *View->Property Editor* menu item) scroll down to the bottom and look for the `currentTabText` property. You can change the tab's name right there.

Comment: Is there a method to set it at runtime, did not see one

Comment: As "none" points out, you cannot choose the tab with the View->"Object Inspector", you have to select the tab in the Edit->"Edit Widgets" view. Poor design if you ask me, but that is how it is...

Comment: The `currentTabText` property is on the `QTabWidget` and not the individual widgets representing each tab.

Comment: Select the parent QTabWidget in Object Inspector.  First select the "currentIndex" corresponding to the tab you would like to alter and hit enter.  Change the name using the currentTabText property.  Continue doing this for all indexes 0-n.

Answer (score 31):

You can use this at runtime:

```
ui->tabWidget->setTabText(index, "New tab title");
```

Answer (score 17):

In Qt Creator/Designer (2.4.1), if you can't seem to find the currentTabText property, you have probably selected the tab itself in the the object tree.

Make sure to select the QTabWidget, which should happen automatically when selecting the tab in the form preview (see richardwb's answer).